# Auto-Decryption Question from Computer Science Circles (Python)

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, python-cryptography

I'm doing this exercise from computer science circle. Here's the information:

> Write a program which does the following. First, it should read one line of input, which is the encoded message, and will consist of capital letters and spaces.
> Your program must try decoding the message with all 26 possible values of the shift S; out of these 26 possible original messages, print the one which has the highest goodness.
> For your convenience, we will pre-define the variable letterGoodness for you, a list of length 26 which equals the values in the frequency table above,
> letterGoodness = [.0817,.0149,.0278,.0425,.1270,.0223,.0202,...

I've done some coding but it kept saying 'list index out of range' at line 24 (the letterGoodness[diff] line). I checked but couldn't find out why.

Here's the code:

```
#subtask 1: shifting values
a = input ()
def Decode(S):
   b = ""
   for i in range (0, len (a)):
      if a[i] != " ":
         if ord(a[i]) + int(S) <= 90:
            c = chr(ord(a[i]) + int(S))
            b = b + c
         else:
            c = chr(ord(a[i]) + int(S) - 65)
            b = b + c
      else:
         b = b + a[i]
   return b
#subtask 2: determining goodness
goodness = 0
maxx = 0
for S in range (1, 27):
   b = Decode (S)
   for ii in range (0, len(b)):
      if b[ii] != " ": 
         diff = (ord(b[ii]) - 65)
         goodness = goodness + letterGoodness[diff]
         if goodness > maxx:
            maxx = goodness
            out = b

print (out)
```

Comment: What is your input?  The code you showed only works if you input `A` through `Z`, any other character, including lowercase letters and spaces , will cause problems (well, some will work by accident)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The input is any capital letter with spaces. Could you please tell me why including spaces could cause errors? Thanks again! :)